# Page turn effect in pdf files

Tags: android

I want page turn effect in my pdf files.
I found page turn effect in images, but was not getting any idea about how to do it in pdf files.
please guide me

Comment: hi  ..i am searching for the same for reading the pdf file with page turning effect..have u got any soln for the same pls suggest me how to read pdf file and use page turning effect ...vv thanks ...waiting f or ur positive reply..vvthanks in advanse...

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing this - both web based a and native solutions. We supply a GPL viewer which has some options for this and a non-GPL viewer which has animated page turn effects. You can find the GPL viewer here:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download/

The non-GPL viewer with a desktop publisher for Mac and PC can be found here:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp

(note: I am affiliated with the solution above)